# Watir returning wrong elements?

Tags: facebook, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm running some code on Facebook app pages, part of a research project. 
I want only two values from the page, and only three values in total fit the condition

```
    b.div(class: "_50f6 _50f7 _5tfx")
```

However, when I try

```
    puts b.div(class: "_50f6 _50f7 _5tfx").text
```

it prints the first (correct) value.

When I do

```
   b.divs(class: "_50f6 _50f7 _5tfx").each do
   |div| puts div.text
```

I get no response.
If I try

```
    b.divs(class: "_50f6 _50f7 _5tfx")[0].text
```

i get a lot of unrelated information that doesn't fit the class condition either.

The page I'm testing is https://www.facebook.com/ClashofClans. 
I use watir to click on the likes button as:

```
    b.link(class: "uiLinkSubtle").click
```

And then use the above to get the information I want, which is the values 693599, 12794001 and 211020 (People talking about this, total likes, new likes).
What's my code doing wrong?

Comment: You are aware that classes like _50f6 will change at any second? And that scraping Facebook is not allowed without written permission from them?

Comment: Yeah, I posted about that earlier. Someone pointed me to their form!
The classes I only need while I get the data, then it's all offline processing.

Comment: The correct syntax for each is b.divs(class: "_50f6 _50f7 _5tfx").each {
   |div| puts div.text }